# PHP sessions not saved properly

Tags: php, session, save

I have a huge problem regarding sessions in php. I am pretty new to php so I probably made a mistake.

The main problem is, that session variables aren't saved properly.
I wrote a little login script with recaptcha an stuff:

```
<?php 
    if (!isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) {
        echo "NOT SET";
?>
    <h1>Authentifikation</h1>
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['authentificate']) && $_POST['authentificate'] == 'Bestätigen') {
        if(!isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response']) || !isset($_POST['username']) || !isset($_POST['userpass'])) {
            MessageHandler('Bitte korrigiere deine Angaben.', 2);
            return;
        }

        $topl_curl = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($topl_curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify');
        curl_setopt($topl_curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_setopt($topl_curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($topl_curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($topl_curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query(array(
            'secret'    => $settings['CAPTCHA']['PRIVATE_KEY'],
            'response'  => $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'],
        )));
        curl_setopt($topl_curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($topl_curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.64 Safari/537.11');
        $topl_data = curl_exec($topl_curl);
        $topl_info = curl_getinfo($topl_curl);

        if (!$topl_info['http_code'] == 200 ) {
            print_r($topl_info);
            echo 'RE-Captcha ERROR';
            return;
        }
        $jResponse = json_decode($topl_data, true);
        if ($jResponse['success']) {
            $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT id, login, cash, status FROM account.account WHERE login LIKE '".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['username'])."' AND password = PASSWORD('".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['userpass'])."') LIMIT 1");
            if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                $info = $result->fetch_object();
                if ($info->status == 'BLOCK' && $settings['MODE'] != 'BEFORE_START') {
                    MessageHandler('Dieser Account ist gesperrt.', 3);
                    return;
                }
                $_SESSION['user_id'] = $info->id;
                $_SESSION['user_name'] = $info->login;
                $_SESSION['user_dr'] = $info->cash;
                MessageHandler('Du wurdest erfolgreich eingeloggt.', 2);
?>
<script>
setTimeout(function() {
        window.location.replace("/index.php?s=login");
}, 3000);
</script>
<?php
            } else {
                MessageHandler('Deine Login Daten sind fehlerhaft, bitte versuche es erneut.');
            }
            return;
        }
    }
?>
<center><p>Bitte authentifizieren Sie sich indem Sie das Captcha ausfüllen.</p></center>
<form method="POST" action="?s=login">
    <center><br><div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="<?=$settings['CAPTCHA']['PUBLIC_KEY'] ?>"></div>
    <input type="hidden" name="username" value="<?=$_POST['username']?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="userpass" value="<?=$_POST['userpass']?>">
    <br><input type="submit" name="authentificate" value="Bestätigen"/></center>
</form>
<?php
    }
    else {
    if (!isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) {
        echo "NOT SET";
    }
?>
<?php
    }
?>
```

I also display session infos to see what happens after executing the script:

```
session_id: aea6434a454efb40851d035612307b25
array(3) { ["user_id"]=> string(1) "1" ["user_name"]=> string(5) "admin" ["user_dr"]=> string(6) "887992" } uid:
session.cookie_domain: 
session file: /var/customers/tmp/censored//sess_aea6434a454efb40851d035612307b25 
size: 59
```

So obviously the settings are set, but after the javascript refreshing after 3 seconds, the following session infos appear:

```
session_id: aea6434a454efb40851d035612307b25
array(0) { } uid:
session.cookie_domain: 
session file: /var/customers/tmp/censored//sess_aea6434a454efb40851d035612307b25 
size: 0
```

I searched a lot to fix this but every question here at stackoverflow which was answered did not help solving my problem.

Do you have any suggestions what to try?
The session_path is set correctly..

Comment: I don't see any `session_start()` in your script.

Comment: yeah, forgot to mention that session_start() is part of my index.php which includes this script (named login.php)

Comment: So, this script is included in your `index.php`?

Comment: yes it is included there